# Disregard component of a Triple in a comparison

Tags: kotlin, tuples

I am attempting to compare `Triple`s while disregarding certain values of the `Triple`. The value I wish to disregard below is signified by `_`. Note the below code is for example purposes and does not compile because `_` is an `Unresolved reference`.

```
val coordinates = Triple(3, 2, 5)
when (coordinates) {
    Triple(0, 0, 0) -> println("Origin")
    Triple(_, 0, 0)-> println("On the x-axis.")
    Triple(0, _, 0)-> println("On the y-axis.")
    Triple(0, 0, _)-> println("On the z-axis.")
    else-> println("Somewhere in space")
}
```

I know you can use `_` when [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations) if you would like to ignore a value but that doesn't seem to help me with the above issue:

```
val (x4, y4, _) = coordinates
println(x4)
println(y4)
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Disregarding a component is one thing, but what you actually expect is full-blown _pattern matching_ to occur, so that `_` stands for "any value acceptable". This is something Kotlin does not support, and there aren't any plans to support it, as far is I could find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Underscore for unused variables was introduced in Kotlin 1.1 and it is designed to be used when some variables are not needed in the destructuring declaration.

In the branch conditions of your when expression, `Triple(0, 0, 0)` is creating an new instance but not destructuring. So, using underscore is not permitted here.

Currently, destructuring in the branch conditions of when expression is not possible in Kotlin. One of the solutions for your case is to compare each of the component verbosely in each branch condition:

```
val (x, y, z) = Triple(3, 2, 5)
when {
    x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0 -> println("Origin")
    y == 0 && z == 0 -> println("On the x-axis.")
    x == 0 && z == 0 -> println("On the y-axis.")
    x == 0 && y == 0 -> println("On the z-axis.")
    else -> println("Somewhere in space")
}
```

[Here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/destructuring-in-when/2391) is a discussion on destructuring in when expression.